# How do I make a dataframe have the same order of rows as another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I make df2 have the same row order as df1 based on column "ID"?

```
 df1             
 ID Var1    Var2    Col1    Col2
 1    34      22      34      24
 2     3      25      54      65
 3    87      68      14      78
 4    66      98      98     100

 df2             
 ID Varx    VarY    ColZ    Col2
 1    134      2      4      4
 2     33      5      4      5
 4    660      8      8      100
 3    87      68      14     78
```

Expected outcome:

```
 df2             
 ID Var1    Var2    Col1    Col2
 1    34      22      34      24
 2     3      25      54      65
 3    87      68      14      78
 4    66      98      98     100
```

Comment: `df2[df1$ID,]` if it is numeric (and assuming both have the same IDs) and not numeric, then use `match` df2[match(df2$ID, df1$ID),]`

Comment: Your df2 above appears to be just a copy of df1.  For that, all you need is:
`df2 <- df1`

Comment: Hi, this was just an example of the data. df1 is actually very different to df2. I'm trying to use Akrun's code but it doesn't seem to work, any suggestions?

Comment: Just to add to the last comment, df2 has negative numbers and decimal places. Both df1 and df2 have the same numbers in the ID column.